Can I use serverTimestamp() in a Firebase Query?
Can I query the Realtime Database using the startAt filter together with serverTimestamp()?
If so, or if not, is this explicitly documented somewhere?

The answer appears to be no. Although I cannot find any documentation - I also cannot get code relying on serverTimestamp() to ever retrieve any information from the server when combined with listeners. I guess it's only for write operations.
